# Several Problems Compiling and running an example C++ Program on Windows

Tags: c++, windows

As you can see, I'm extremely new to this site. I've searched using to find problems like mine, but to no avail.

What my problem is, is that I cannot compile a c++ program ([link here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Glescraft_1) Note: source code is found [here](https://gitorious.org/wikibooks-opengl/modern-tutorials/trees/master)), and have found no proper ways to fix the compiler errors.

I have tried several ways to compile:

**1) Using cygwin.**

I used the makefile provided to compile and tried to run the file (I had many problems with including the libraries (GLEW, GLUT, GLM) but I fixed them after putting the libraries in the cygwin directory. Then it gave me a freeglut failed to open display error, which I fixed going into xcygwin. This gave me a final error calling a missing GL version. People on other sites have said to initiate glut before glew, but I couldn't find where init glew was run. I have found no soutions to the cygwin problem.

**2) Using the g++ compiler through CMD.exe**

I read you can compile C++ through command prompt, so I tried to do that. 
I ran the command g++ glescraft.cpp noise.h noise.cpp textures.c -o glescraft, but also gave errors about not being able to find GLEW. I fixed these yet again by putting the libraries in the correct place. After all the library issues had been fixed, it threw many issues about multiple declarations, and also undefined references to GL, GLEW, and GLUT commands. I can post the errors if yo guys need them by the way. But, I don't believe there is a programming error in the files, as the program compiled using make on GNU/Linux perfectly fine, but I couldn't test due to myself having many issues with the nVIDIA drivers (X not starting etc etc). I tried a g++ compile on gnu/linux as well but the same multiple definitions and undefined references. I couldn't find anything on these.

**3)Code::Blocks**

The exact same thing happened was using the g++ compiler, as I believe code::blocks uses the mingw g++ compiler too.

By the way, when I said I tried g++ in the command prompt, I also tried gcc, but also, same errors.

My Question is, how can I get this program to compile, and with little dependencies as possible?

Can you guys find a way? I'm stumped, and cannot find a way to do this at all, I've been trying for a week or so as well.

EDIT: As a person pointed out, here are the errors:

The errors shown after using the g++ compiler in cmd and also the same as the ones shown in code::blocks:

```
C:\prog\glescraft>g++ glescraft.cpp noise.h noise.cpp textures.c -o glescraft.ex
e
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccCAHbwO.o:noise.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple d
efinition of `linearInterpolation(float, float, float)'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x58): first
 defined here
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccCAHbwO.o:noise.cpp:(.text+0x11): multiple
definition of `biLinearInterpolation(float, float, float, float, float, float)'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x69): first
 defined here
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccCAHbwO.o:noise.cpp:(.text+0x76): multiple
definition of `triLinearInterpolation(float, float, float, float, float, float,
float, float, float, float, float)'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0xce): first
 defined here
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccCAHbwO.o:noise.cpp:(.text+0x111): multiple
 definition of `noise2d(int, int, int)'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x169): firs
t defined here
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccCAHbwO.o:noise.cpp:(.text+0x1e7): multiple
 definition of `noise3d(int, int, int, int)'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x23f): firs
t defined here
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccCAHbwO.o:noise.cpp:(.text+0x2f4): multiple
 definition of `noise2d_gradient(float, float, int)'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x34c): firs
t defined here
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccCAHbwO.o:noise.cpp:(.text+0x454): multiple
 definition of `noise3d_gradient(float, float, float, int)'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x4ac): firs
t defined here
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccCAHbwO.o:noise.cpp:(.text+0x6e0): multiple
 definition of `noise2d_perlin(float, float, int, int, float)'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x738): firs
t defined here
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccCAHbwO.o:noise.cpp:(.text+0x765): multiple
 definition of `noise2d_perlin_abs(float, float, int, int, float)'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x7bd): firs
t defined here
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccCAHbwO.o:noise.cpp:(.text+0x7f6): multiple
 definition of `noise3d_perlin(float, float, float, int, int, float)'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x84e): firs
t defined here
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccCAHbwO.o:noise.cpp:(.text+0x885): multiple
 definition of `noise3d_perlin_abs(float, float, float, int, int, float)'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x8dd): firs
t defined here
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x1c): undef
ined reference to `__glutInitWithExit'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x37): undef
ined reference to `__glutCreateWindowWithExit'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x52): undef
ined reference to `__glutCreateMenuWithExit'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0xa9e): unde
fined reference to `_imp____glewIsShader'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0xab9): unde
fined reference to `_imp____glewGetShaderiv'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0xadc): unde
fined reference to `_imp____glewIsProgram'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0xaf7): unde
fined reference to `_imp____glewGetProgramiv'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0xb55): unde
fined reference to `_imp____glewIsShader'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0xb70): unde
fined reference to `_imp____glewGetShaderInfoLog'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0xb9a): unde
fined reference to `_imp____glewIsProgram'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0xbb5): unde
fined reference to `_imp____glewGetProgramInfoLog'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0xc51): unde
fined reference to `_imp____glewCreateShader'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0xc66): unde
fined reference to `_imp____glewShaderSource'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0xc9a): unde
fined reference to `_imp____glewCompileShader'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0xcb3): unde
fined reference to `_imp____glewGetShaderiv'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0xd05): unde
fined reference to `_imp____glewDeleteShader'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0xe48): unde
fined reference to `glGetIntegerv@8'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0xefc): unde
fined reference to `_imp____glewCreateProgram'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0xf14): unde
fined reference to `_imp____glewAttachShader'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0xf2f): unde
fined reference to `_imp____glewAttachShader'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0xf4a): unde
fined reference to `_imp____glewLinkProgram'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0xf5e): unde
fined reference to `_imp____glewGetProgramiv'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0xfc1): unde
fined reference to `_imp____glewGetAttribLocation'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x1025): und
efined reference to `_imp____glewGetUniformLocation'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x1082): und
efined reference to `_imp____glewActiveTexture'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x10ae): und
efined reference to `glGenTextures@8'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x10c6): und
efined reference to `glBindTexture@8'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x1119): und
efined reference to `glTexImage2D@36'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x1121): und
efined reference to `_imp____glewGenerateMipmap'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x1211): und
efined reference to `_imp____glewGenBuffers'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x1244): und
efined reference to `_imp____glewBindBuffer'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x1260): und
efined reference to `_imp____glewBufferData'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x128d): und
efined reference to `_imp____glewGenBuffers'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x134e): und
efined reference to `glViewport@16'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x13a2): und
efined reference to `_imp____glewUseProgram'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x13b6): und
efined reference to `_imp____glewUniform1i'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x14f8): und
efined reference to `_imp____glewUniformMatrix4fv'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x1552): und
efined reference to `glClearColor@16'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x1561): und
efined reference to `glClear@4'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x1580): und
efined reference to `glTexParameteri@12'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x159f): und
efined reference to `glTexParameteri@12'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x15ae): und
efined reference to `glEnable@4'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x15bd): und
efined reference to `glEnable@4'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x15d6): und
efined reference to `glPolygonOffset@8'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x15e5): und
efined reference to `glEnable@4'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x15ed): und
efined reference to `_imp____glewEnableVertexAttribArray'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x1666): und
efined reference to `glReadPixels@28'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x1e72): und
efined reference to `glDisable@4'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x1e81): und
efined reference to `glDisable@4'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x1e89): und
efined reference to `_imp____glewUniformMatrix4fv'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x1ec0): und
efined reference to `_imp____glewBindBuffer'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x1edc): und
efined reference to `_imp____glewBufferData'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x1f09): und
efined reference to `_imp____glewVertexAttribPointer'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x1f5c): und
efined reference to `glDrawArrays@12'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x1f83): und
efined reference to `glDisable@4'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x1fa7): und
efined reference to `_imp____glewUniformMatrix4fv'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x1fde): und
efined reference to `_imp____glewBindBuffer'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x1ffa): und
efined reference to `_imp____glewBufferData'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x2027): und
efined reference to `_imp____glewVertexAttribPointer'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x207a): und
efined reference to `glDrawArrays@12'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x2082): und
efined reference to `glutSwapBuffers'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x22f4): und
efined reference to `glutGet'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x24d7): und
efined reference to `glutPostRedisplay'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x2643): und
efined reference to `glutWarpPointer'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x2825): und
efined reference to `_imp____glewDeleteProgram'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x2862): und
efined reference to `glutInitDisplayMode'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x2876): und
efined reference to `glutInitWindowSize'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x2887): und
efined reference to `_imp__glewInit'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x28a0): und
efined reference to `_imp__glewGetErrorString'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x28ce): und
efined reference to `_imp____GLEW_VERSION_2_0'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x296c): und
efined reference to `glutSetCursor'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x2980): und
efined reference to `glutWarpPointer'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x298c): und
efined reference to `glutDisplayFunc'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x2998): und
efined reference to `glutReshapeFunc'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x29a4): und
efined reference to `glutIdleFunc'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x29b0): und
efined reference to `glutSpecialFunc'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x29bc): und
efined reference to `glutSpecialUpFunc'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x29c8): und
efined reference to `glutIdleFunc'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x29d4): und
efined reference to `glutPassiveMotionFunc'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x29e0): und
efined reference to `glutMotionFunc'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x29ec): und
efined reference to `glutMouseFunc'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text+0x29f1): und
efined reference to `glutMainLoop'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text$_ZN5chunk6up
dateEv[chunk::update()]+0x237e): undefined reference to `_imp____glewGenBuffers'

C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text$_ZN5chunk6up
dateEv[chunk::update()]+0x23e9): undefined reference to `_imp____glewBindBuffer'

C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text$_ZN5chunk6up
dateEv[chunk::update()]+0x2409): undefined reference to `_imp____glewBufferData'

C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text$_ZN5chunk6re
nderEv[chunk::render()]+0x3f): undefined reference to `_imp____glewBindBuffer'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text$_ZN5chunk6re
nderEv[chunk::render()]+0x5f): undefined reference to `_imp____glewVertexAttribP
ointer'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text$_ZN5chunk6re
nderEv[chunk::render()]+0xb7): undefined reference to `glDrawArrays@12'
C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL5KhgI.o:glescraft.cpp:(.text$_ZN10superch
unk6renderERKN3glm6detail7tmat4x4IfEE[superchunk::render(glm::detail::tmat4x4 const&)]+0x2c7): undefined reference to `_imp____glewUniformMatrix4fv'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Sorry about the formatting, I can't seem to get the code tags working on a copy-paste.

Comment: The [`compile.txt`](https://gitorious.org/wikibooks-opengl/modern-tutorials/blobs/master/compile.txt) in there indicates the code is designed for Linux. I don't see any evidence that it's designed to run on Windows at all. Have you tried building on Linux?

Comment: Yes, I have, but I know GLUT, GLEW and GLM should work on Windows.

As I said, I cannot run the code, due to the "free" drivers do not support 3D, and the proprietary drivers I can't get working either.

There is a page that sets up this project in code::blocks, but as I described in my question, it throws the same errors as the g++ cmd compile method.

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Installation/Windows

That is the set up page on Windows.

Comment: You might want to include the *actual* compiler errors you're getting in your question. Not only will your question be easier to answer (right now nobody except you can tell why your code doesn't build), but it will help others who search for the same error messages later.

Comment: Thanks for that! Added some, but unfortunately, being new, I haven't learnt how to properly use the code tag.

Comment: Indent everything 4 spaces. Easiest way is to select it all and hit Ctrl+K or the `{}` button.

Comment: Oh thanks, that's useful to know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of those multiple definition error is because the file glescraft.cpp includes the *source* file of noise.cpp and textures.c, and you also try to compile with on the command line. Either change the source to include proper header files, or compile only glescraft.cpp.

The problems with undefined references is because you do not link with the OpenGL libraries. Add at least "-lgl -lglut" to the command line.

You also need to tell the compiler (actually the linker) where to find the libraries. This is done with the "-L" flag.

The command line after my suggestions should look something like:

```
g++ glescraft.cpp -o glescraft.exe -L<path to gl and glut libs> -lgl -lglut
```

Replace "`<path to gl and glut libs>`" with the actual path to the libraries.

Also, when compiling, header files (files ending in ".h") should never be compiled by you. Instead they are included by the compiler with the `#include "file"` directive.

You can see all flags in the [GCC manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/). Select the version you have (which can be found with the command `g++ --version`.)

Comment: Now I'm getting an error showing `C:\prog\glescraft>g++ glescraft.cpp -o glescraft.exe -lgl -lglut
c:/program files (x86)/codeblocks/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.1/../../../..
/mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgl
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`

How would I fix this linker problem? I'm assuming the same thing will happen once the -lgl problem is fixed.

Comment: @AnotherNewCPPDev The error states that the library "gl" can not be found. You need to tell the linker where to find them. Updated answer to reflect this.

Comment: I can't seem to find the libraries, @Joachim Pileborg. Is it just called gl.lib? 
Also, are you sure it's lowercase gl?
the makefile says `LDLIBS=-lm -lglut -lGL -lGLEW32 -std=c++0x
CXXFLAGS=-O6 -ffast-math -Wall
all: glescraft
` Which seems to suggest the tag should be -lGL (no result also)

So where is the most likely place for the library files? I've searched for files with the name gl, but nothing has come up for me (other than files which seemed unrelated). 
TL;DR: Where is the gl library located, and if for some reason, it is not located on my computer, where is it available?

Comment: Okay, I'm progressing through, but I'm still having errors pertaining to find the GL library.

The Glut and GLEW ones are working fine, it's just that it throws an error with the -lgl arg. When I change it to -lopenGL32, the it passes, but then throws up the errors of undefined references.

What's more, is that the compilation works totally fine on ubuntu, due to the fact I had installed all of the necessary components of the build.


So, is there a similar way to get the command line compilation working on Windows? I cannot for the life of me find any way at all to get this working.